# How to insert a random integer number, for a given column and several rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I was wondering.. Is it possible, with a SQL query, to:

- generate randomly, a list of integer number
- insert this in a table, for a specific column, and for multiple rows

I didn't try anything, to be honest I was just asking myself the question.

EDIT:  (from a comment)

Imagine that I have a table USERS, with a field named VOTES. For every users, I want to insert, in the column VOTES, a random integer number between 0 and 15. For the record, I'm working with MySQL 5.5 | MariaDB

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Provide sample data to be clear what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Imagine that I have a table USERS, with a field named VOTES.
For every users, I want to insert, in the column VOTES, a random integer number between 0 and 15.

For the record, I'm working with MySQL 5.5 | MariaDB

Comment: You shouldn't add question details in a comment. You should edit your question. Click on the _edit_ link below the tags in your question.

Comment: @Abra you're right, sorry for missing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update the column named `votes` in the table `users` with random integers between 0 and 15, you could do it in the following:

```
UPDATE users
    SET votes = FLOOR(RAND() * 16)
```